# AWS DocumentDB change stream data availability from default to 24 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, changestream, aws-documentdb

Started to use AWS DocumentDb change stream, want to keep Events written to a change stream for a database for 24 hours instead of default 3 hours. 
How I can do this.
Standard AWS docs provide just this:

```
db.adminCommand({modifyChangeStreams: 1,
    database: "",
    collection: "", 
    enable: true   
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 'Parameter groups' on AWS Document Db console.
Choose your cluster group if created, if not use default.
There are several cluster parameters available, one of them: `change_stream_log_retention_duration`, max value can be `86400` which is 24 hours in seconds.
Haven't had permissions to see that.
Hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

ekaterina@, you are correct, the docs for change streams are not clear and we will fix that. You can change the default retention period change_stream_log_retention_duration to 24 hours. Here are the docs on how to change cluster parameters, in general:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/cluster_parameter_groups-parameters.html